# Database structure is from newer Gammu version

Tags: upgrade, postgresql-9.1, sms-gateway, gamma-function, gammu

i get error when run gammu-smsd

```
Log filename is "/var/log/gammu-smsd"
gammu-smsd[11271]: Database structure is from newer Gammu version
gammu-smsd[11271]: Initialisation failed, stopping Gammu smsd: Unknown error. (UNKNOWN[27])
Failed to run SMSD: Unknown error.
```

my gammu in version 1.31.90 and database structure in version 1.34.0.

i try upgrade gammu version

```
apt-get upgrade gammu
```

but gammu version stil in version 1.31.90

can you help me solve this problem?

thank you

Comment: Well, how'd you get data from a newer version there in the first place? Did you load this database from another server? Something else?

Answer (score 1):

There is a sql file to setup the postgres DB in docs/sql/pgsql.sql. It can be found online here: http://wammu.eu/docs/manual/smsd/pgsql.html

This line is causing trouble:

INSERT INTO gammu ("Version") VALUES (14);

Change '14' to '13' and rerun the script to build your smsd database. This worked for me... 
All the best, Sebastian